# I'm trying to update the textview in the recyclerview after clicking add and delete button. notifyDataSetChanged(); method is not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My onclick delete and add button is in the adapter class under MyViewHolder class.
I managed to delete and add data to server. but its not updating from the recyclerview. Below is my adapter class. I used volley library to send the request, delete request was pain in my a**s , so i changed that to post method. but thats not the problem im facing now. i just want update the reserved amount which displayed on the recyclerview.. thanks

```html
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<Cart> cartList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Cart cart;
    private int inventoryId;
    private String username;
    private CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    private String url = "http://192.168.4.31/api/canteen/cart";
    private String delete_url = "http://192.168.4.31/api/canteen/mobile_delete";
    String qtyReserved;

    public static boolean add= true;
    public static int sum = 0;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView thumbnail, plus, minus;
        public TextView menuName, quantity_reserved, price ;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            menuName = view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            quantity_reserved = view.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            plus = view.findViewById(R.id.plusImage);
            minus = view.findViewById(R.id.minusImage);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            plus.setOnClickListener(this);
            minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            cart = cartList.get(getAdapterPosition());
            inventoryId = cart.getCart_inv_id();
            username = cart.getScreen_name();


            if (view.getId() == plus.getId()) {
                putToCart(getAdapterPosition());
               // cartAdapter.notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            if (view.getId() == minus.getId()) {
                deleteFromCart(getAdapterPosition());
              //  notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),cartList.size());

            }

        }
    }


    public CartAdapter(Context context, List<Cart> images) {
        mContext = context;
        this.cartList = images;
      this.cartAdapter = this;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cart_thumbnail, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        cart = cartList.get(position);
        String url_image = "http://192.168.4.31";
        String name = cart.getImg_url();
        String finalurl = "";
        finalurl = url_image + name;

        Glide.with(mContext).load(finalurl)
                .thumbnail(0.3f)
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.lunch)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.menuName.setText(cartList.get(position).getCart_inv_name());
        holder.quantity_reserved.setText(Integer.toString(cartList.get(position).getQuantity_reserved()));
        holder.price.setText(Double.toString(cartList.get(position).getTotal())+"0");
      //  refreshBlockOverlay(position);

//        if(add){
//            sum = sum + cart.getQuantity_reserved();
//            add= false; }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartList.size();
    }

    public void putToCart(final int position) {

        JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
        try {
            param.put("screen_name", username);
            param.put("inventory_id", inventoryId);
            param.put("pending", "null");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, param,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            qtyReserved = response.getString("amount_reserved");
                            Cart image = new Cart();
                            image.setQuantity_reserved(Integer.valueOf(qtyReserved));
                            cartList.add(image);
                          //  notifyItemInserted(position);
                           notifyItemRangeChanged(position , getItemCount());



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Oops!! Now its not available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        MySingleton.mySingletonInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(request_json);
    }

    public void deleteFromCart(final int position2) {
        JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
        try {
            param.put("screen_name", username);
            param.put("inventory_id", inventoryId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, delete_url, param,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       //  notifyItemRemoved(position2);
                        //notifyItemRangeChanged();
                      // notifyItemRemoved(position2);
                       // notifyItemChanged(position2);
                        //notifyItemRangeChanged(position2, 1, null);
                     //  cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "not ok " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        MySingleton.mySingletonInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(request_json);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Following this site rules, you should include code that is on the screenshots in the post as text.

Comment: Just a guess - try to call notify() from UI thread.

Comment: I tried to call notify() method also, nothing happen,,

Comment: i tried almost all the notify method

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting data from server but you are still keeping it in app memory in your list. On succesfull server response you should delete it from the list and then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: above is adapter class

Comment: so while deleting, in on onResponse method put cartList.remove(position2) before notifyDataSetChanged(). Let me now if it helped

Comment: it is removing whole row

Comment: I thought thats what you wanted to do. So what exactly you want to happen after delete?

Comment: xml layout in recyclerview ,there are add, delete button and quantity textview is present in the cart. once i click the add button, it add one stock to cart and vice versa. but its is not showing in the textview that i have added the one stock the cart.. eg: first available stock is 20, but after click to add button it must change to 21.